# Is it possible to create a framework which contains multiple UIViewcontrollers into it?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

**Login Module: Splash, login, registration, forgot password, Menubar**

I have 5 different applications on iOS & Android platforms. I have common login and some other modules with common API calls. I have a common design for Login Modules in all 5 applications with only the background colour and application logo changed into it.

Now in android, we can export those modules in .aar files along with UI design and can use them in all 5 projects. This reduces our time and we do not have to copy and paste complete code. I can define/give different images for icons in android from outside of the module as well. In this way, we can show different logos and different applications.

Now I want to perform the same task on the iOS platform as well. So is there any way where I can create login modules once and then attach them to another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract your shared code into a local [Swift Package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/swift-packages) and use it in any app you want.